# Edward and Bruce

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, history, puzzle-history

> *Turning* my back on you
>
> *A la* a dramatic insult
>
> Like Edward and Bruce

---

> `Q  U  W  Z  T  F`
> `Z  '  Q  A  Q`
> `U  X  T  R  O`
> `S  X  U  R  M`
> `Y  Y  Y  Q  Z`
> `M  M  M  D  '`

---

> I spoke for him
>
> But I am not big and furry
>
> **Where was I born?**

Hint 1:

> There are 5/6 persons hinted to in this puzzle:
>  **[puzzle-history]** is hinting to person A
>  **Part one:** Person A is historical, persons B and E are fictional characters.
>  **Part two:** Person A and person E are giving the key, and will reveal the fictional character V and the historical person M.
>  **Part three:** Person M will help reveal the historical person S. Where is person S born?

Hint 2:

> There are four different clues in this puzzle all pointing to the same key!

Hint 3:

> Vertical Caesar

Comment: Um, why on earth was this flagged as "unclear what you're asking"? It's an ***enigmatic puzzle*** - it's *supposed* to be unclear at this stage!

Comment: I've seen this happen before with enigmatic-puzzles.

Comment: For the record, what I actually is asking is: "Where was I born?"

Comment: Not really an enigmatic puzzle, as is, though.  Just a series of encrypted letters, followed by possibly related sentences, with no justification of connection.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think you just fail to see the enigma at first glance...

Comment: FWIW, the first letters spell out TALIB. Which is possibly Taliban. If that's anywhere close(I hope not), then where they were born is a controversial thing to answer..

Comment: @Sid Nothing to do with Taliban, that is a pure coincidence! But your puzzle technique could help you..

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Edward the Bruce, Robert the Bruce, and/or King Edward?

Comment: @wildBillMunson no

Comment: Can we assume that person or thing is a real historical entity - that is to say, not based on fiction or myth?

Comment: @wildBillMunson What person or thing are you referring to? There are at least 5 persons hinted to in this puzzle, where two are fictional, and three are historical persons.

Comment: I noticed you used the 'history' tag. I've seen that one thrown in there before erroneously...just checking.

Comment: @wildBillMunson I even used the "puzzle-history" tag, but someone disagreed ant edited it out...

Comment: Seems a bit presumptuous to make that edit, especially given the enigmatic-puzzle tag. I would vote to revert back to 'puzzle-history'.

Comment: (Potential spoilers in this comment.) Based on the new hint I'm guessing that Bruce and Edward refer to Bruce Wayne and Edward Nygma, i.e., Batman and Riddler.

Comment: @Enigma I made an edit - let me know if I messed anything up, and I can roll back.

Comment: @randal'thor perfect! Thx!

Comment: Please see the feedback section I just edited into my answer - and apologies in advance if it feels too harsh :-) I suggest you **un-spoiler-tag Hint 1**, as the puzzle isn't really solvable without it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edward and Bruce*

After spending quite a while researching Robert the Bruce, his younger brother [Edward Bruce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Bruce), and other related historical figures, I hit upon the idea of considering

> Edward Nygma and Bruce Wayne, also known as **the Riddler** and **Batman**, a pair of famous fictional foes.

---

*Turning my back on you*
*A la a dramatic insult*
*Like Edward and Bruce*

> The spoilertagged hint tells us that we should be looking for a historical character A who's somehow related to puzzle history. When I noticed the italicisation of the words "Turning" and "A la", I realised that these words together form an anagram of **Alan Turing**. He worked on cracking the Enigma code, which links to the E character via " E Nygma". I'm not sure if there's any riddlish meaning in the first two lines, or if they're just meant for wordplay.

*QUWZTF*
*Z'QAQ*
*UXTRO*
*SXURM*
*YYYQZ*
*MMMD'*

> As [Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47823/5373) discovered, this is a Caesar-shifted cipher intended to be read vertically. Shifting each letter backwards by 10 places gives:
>
>  `E I K N H T`
>  `N ' E O E`
>  `I L H F C`
>  `G L I F A`
>  `M M M E N`
>  `A A A R '`
>
>  and hence the message "ENIGMA" (confirmation) "I'LL MAKE HIM AN OFFER HE CAN'T".

Clearly, the word to finish off

> this famous (mis)quote is REFUSE. The quote itself is from **Vito Corleone** (the fictional character V), played in the film *The Godfather* by **Marlon Brando** (the historical character M).

---

*I spoke for him*
*But I am not big and furry*
*Where was I born?*

> Searching Google for "spoke for Marlon Brando" led me to **[Sacheen Littlefeather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacheen_Littlefeather)**, who "gave a speech at the 45th Academy Awards ceremony on March 27, 1973, for actor Marlon Brando, who was declining the Academy Award for Best Actor which he had won for his performance in The Godfather". She is indeed not big and furry - her name is instead "little" and "feather"ed. And the fact that Brando declined the Academy Award links back to the missing word REFUSE from the previous part of the puzzle.

**So the final answer is**

> [Salinas, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salinas,_California), the birthplace of this actress.

---

**Feedback section**

Hints 2 and 3 are, as hints should be, not really necessary. But without Hint 1, this puzzle would be more or less unsolvable. Three short lines of poetry in the 1st part, of which only four words are actually used, aren't really enough to find the required word, nor is the unfinished quote in the 2nd part enough to discover the correct people for the 3rd part, without knowing the information in Hint 1.

Also, the different parts of the puzzle don't fit together as well as they could. Ideally, the 1st part would give a solution which would then be used to decipher the 2nd part, whose solution would then slot into the 3rd part. Instead we have the 1st and 2nd part solvable independently, the 1st part and a chunk of the 2nd giving a solution which is then never used again, and only the rest of the 2nd part giving the solution which is then used in the 3rd part. It feels ... disjointed, with too many red herrings.

Comment: Good try! Archimedes is not correct however. There is a clue for person A in the first verse.

Comment: @Enigma Oops, I forgot to include my reasoning for why Archimedes fits. Edited.

Comment: Nice! But how is Archimedes related to Bruce and/or Edward?

Comment: Good guess.  You could've saved the B+E time by reading my [comment from a couple days ago](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47488/edward-and-bruce#comment144529_47488).  :P    I was thinking the first two lines refer to a duel ("turning my back on you") as duels could be started by "dramatic insult[s]."  But I couldn't think of an A name that's historical and known for duels and puzzling.  I was mainly focusing on names related to ciphers, thinking that that name gives us the cipher and then "riddler" or "nygma" or whatever would be the key.

Comment: @Enigma (after Hint 2) Perhaps the key is something like RIDDLE or RIDDLER or ENIGMA, and both the mysterious A and the already-found E are pointing to this same key?

Comment: @randal'thor Perhaps...

Comment: @Enigma I just had an AHA moment. Stand by for edits ...

Comment: Precisely, this is an AHA puzzle...:-)

Comment: @randal'thor you are on the right track now. Try to figure out who's who in hint 1, and you are close to solving it completely:-)

Comment: @Enigma Solved! (And before I even saw your last comment.)

Comment: @randal'thor correct! Congrats:-)

Comment: Oh. WTH. I was reading that as "Turning" :D Cool.

Comment: @randal'thor do you see the connection between "refuse" and that Brando refused to accept the Oscar for the Godfather...?

Comment: @Enigma I hadn't - nice! Is there any meaning I'm missing in the first two lines of the puzzle, or is most of that just to make it sound meaningful after the important words "turning" and "a la"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The word Enigma is hinted to four times: Alan Turning, Edward Nygma, the tag "enigmatic-puzzle" and of course my own username:-)

Answer (score 1):

> Q  U  W  Z  T  F
>   Z  '  Q  A  Q
>   U  X  T  R  O
>   S  X  U  R  M
>   Y  Y  Y  Q  Z
>   M  M  M  D  '

With latest hint

> Caesar 14 shift gives
>  
>  E  I  K  N  H  T
>  N  '  E  O  E
>  I  L  H  F  C
>  G  L  I  F  A
>  M  M  M  E  N
>  A  A  A  R  '
>  
>  -> **ENIGMA I'LL MAKE HIM AN OFFER HE CAN'T**
>
>  Completing the phrase we get **ENIGMA I'LL MAKE HIM AN OFFER HE CAN'T REFUSE** (Thanks @Rand) which makes it [Al Martino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Martino) who was born in **Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, United States**  / [Vito Carolene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vito_Corleone) who was born in **Corleone, Sicily**. (Godfather)

Comment: You broke the cipher! But not the puzzle, yet...?

Comment: Search the internet for your phrase with REFUSE on the end ;-)

Comment: You are closer now, but I would advice you to re-read the complete puzzle

Comment: @Enigma Updated with the birth places. Am I right or am I going on a wrong track here?

Comment: @Techidiot you have one of the fictional characters correct, and none of the historical character...!